# Generating all n-bit strings whose hamming distance is n/2

Tags: string, algorithm, math, combinatorics

I'm playing with some variant of [Hadamard matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). I want to generate **all** *n*-bit binary strings which satisfy these requirements:

1. You can assume that *n* is a multiple of 4.
2. The first string is 0<sup>n</sup>.
   → a string of all 0s.
3. The remaining strings are sorted in alphabetic order.
   → 0 comes before 1.
4. Every two distinct *n*-bit strings have [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) *n/2*.
   → Two distinct *n*-bit strings agree in exactly *n/2* positions and disagree in exactly *n/2* positions.
5. Due to the above condition, every string except for the first string must have the same number of 0s and 1s.
    → Every string other than the first string must have *n/2* ones and *n/2* zeros.
6. (*Updated*) All the *n*-bit strings begin with `0`.

For example, this is the list that I want for when *n=4*.

> `0000`
>   `0011`
>   `0101`
>   `0110`

You can easily see that every two distinct rows have hamming distance *n/2 = 4/2 = 2* and the list satisfies all the other requirements as well.

Note that I want to generate **all** such strings. My algorithm may just output three strings `0000`, `0011`, and `0101` before terminating. This list  satisfies all the requirements above but it misses `0110`.

1. What would be a good way to generate such sets? 
   A python pseudo-code is preferred but any high-level description will do.
2. What is the **maximum** number of such strings for a given *n*?
   For example, when *n=4*, the max number of such strings happen to be 4. I'm wondering whether there can be any closed form solution for this upper bound.

Thanks.

Comment: These lists are not unique. For example, here are 3 other lists that satisfy your criteria: {0000,0110,1010,1100}, {0000,0011,1001,1010}, {0000,0101,1001,1100}. Do you also want to generate all such lists?

Comment: @Matt Oops. I forgot to mention it. All the n-bit strings begin with 0. Then I think it guarantees that there exists only one such a list. Sounds reasonable?

Comment: Could you post an example for n = 8 ?

Comment: I believe adding requirement number 6 makes the list unique for `n = 4` but not for `n = 8`. For example, `{00000000, 00001111, 00110011, 00111100, 01010101, 01011010, 01100110, 01101001}` and `{00000000. 00001111, 00110101, 00111010, 01010011, 01011100, 01100110, 01101001}`

Comment: I would remove restriction number 6, and add a question 3: for a given `n`, how many maximal sets exist?

Comment: If you have a list, then any permutation of {1,...,n} applied to the elements of the list will give another list.  Matt's example takes OP's and (1) switches 1 and 4, (2) switches 1 and 2, and (3) switches 1 and 3.  mbratch's example switches 6 and 7.  You could take care of this by asking for the lowest such list among equivalent lists (where lowest is lexigraphically defined?).  This doesn't help question 3, since we haven't shown there are no other lists, and we've double counted lists ((1) is also the reversal of OP's lists).

Comment: @Teepeemm to a degree, different "max sets" are bit-permuted versions of other ones. But under the conditions of the problem where we are looking at the bit strings as ordered strings, they should be considered as different solutions. Another way to think of it is if you represent the elements in decimal, then they really are different subsets of numbers. In my example for n = 8, I don't think it's a double count. That said, there will be, as you say, a "lowest such list" and any symmetry in solutions might be used to an advantage in an algorithm that generates the others.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1,

Starting with a string of `n` zeros (let's call it `s0`) and a string of `n/2` zeros followed by `n/2` 1's (call it `s1`), generate the next permutation (call it `p`):

```
scan string from right to left
replace first occurrence of "01" with "10"
(unless the first occurrence is at the string start)
move all "1"'s that are on the right of the "01" to the string end
return replaced string
```

Use the permutation generation order to keep a record of permutations added to sets. If the number of bits set in `xor`ing `p` with each number currently in the set is n/2, add `p` to the list; otherwise, if the number of bits set in `xor`ing `p` with `s1` is n/2 and `p` has not been recorded, start a new set search with `s0`, `s1`; and `p` only as an additional condition for the xor test (since the primary search will review all permutations, this set need not generate additional sets). Use `p` to generate the next permutation.

Comment: How do you know that this will generate the list of maximum length?

Comment: @mbratch It looks like the algorithm will generate all possible sets (that include the string of `n` zeros and the string of `n/2` zeros followed by `n/2` 1's) for a given `n`, no?